# Windows 8.1 Dual Boot Ubuntu 14.04 - dmraid and fixpart

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, inspiron, gpt

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 4.14 on dual boot with Windows 8.1, but when beginning the LiveUSB the Ubuntum, the partitions created by Windows 8.1 are not recognized, reports that all is HD as unallocated, recognizing only the mSATA/SSD. Searching in some forums, I saw what may be:

I ) The mSATA drive of the notebook (Dell Inspiron 15r SE).

II ) The windows 8 has a tag called GPT prevents access to the HD.

I saw that to solve this(I), would have to run the commands:

```
 1. sudo dmraid -r -E /dev/sda
 2. sudo dmraid -r -E /dev/sdb
```

And to solve the "problem" of GPT marking(II), I would have to remove it, running the command:

> fixpart / dev / sdu (u = partition for Ubuntu installation).

Note: An error appears when I start gparted by Live USB Ubuntu, probably by GPT marking, but i can access all partitions with the Ubuntu file manager..

However, as I am a beginner, do not know how safe it is. There reported that it would cause the mSATA was no longer used as chache for Windows 8.1. If that's okay, because I use the mSATA for common storage, not as chache.
Already deactivated the quick launch windows and already ran the "powercfg -h off" (to sleep).
Anyway, does anyone have any tips on these commands, if there is any risk of loss of data, etc.
Is there any way to accomplish this dual boot without the need to format the Windows 8.1?

Thanks!

Comment: DO NOT run fixparts on a Windows pre-installed system. You have to have gpt partitioning for Windows to work. If an Ultrabook you may have data from Intel SRT that does have RAID data on drive. But new versions of Ubuntu will install if you just change UEFI settings to AHCI from Intel SRT. If primarily a Linux user you can use the SSD for / (root) and make Ubuntu very fast. But then Windows does not have its cache. Just using it for data is mostly a waste.

Comment: Please post the output of the following three commands, typed from an Ubuntu live CD: `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`, `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`, and `sudo parted /dev/sda print`. Repeat these for additional disks if there are any. This output will give us the information we need to properly diagnose the problem rather than take stabs in the dark. You can edit your question to add this information.